# Is there any restriction in defining constants in PHP?

Tags: php, constants

Should I define constant and use it?

OR

Can I use Magic numbers?

I am working in project where I am using Magic number in many places do I want to change it? because I am using more that 1000 Magic number? Is this rite way or I should use constant?

Is there any restriction in the number of constants?

Ex:

```
 Magic numbers:
    $common->getDBMessage(25);
 Constants:
    $common->getDBMessage(ERROR_MESSAGE_INVALID_PHONE);
```

Comment: What is 'magic numbers' in your issue context? Could you provide a sample of code that makes you hesitate?

Comment: a specific numeric constant in the middle of the code

Comment: Just numbers! 1,2,3,4,5.... Those are id numbers of messages..

Comment: 1) this is opinion-based, so off topic 2) without seeing the specific code, it's impossible to tell

Comment: If they're ID numbers of messages, why not create a lookup array of names to numbers, so you can use meaningful names for the messages rather than having to remember that id 2 is your INVALID_LOGIN message

Comment: you cannot redefine constants. I've worked on project when the current lang was a constant. Wrong choice, because sometimes it needed to change it for small pieces of code

Comment: Using magic numbers in place of constants is *not* opinion based.

Comment: @chunkiu: are you saying that you can redefine numeric literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many constants as you like. PHP already has a very large number of constants built in.

You might want to consider making them class constants (`const` within a class) rather than global constants (using `define`). Having them organised will help you structure your code better and make things easier to work with.

In addition, if some of the constants are related, you might consider using bit-masks for groups of values, so you can specify them together. This will avoid the need to create an additional constant for the combined value.

But all this is just advice for making your life easier; it's not related to whether you *can* do it or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions for constants in PHP - at least, no native restrictions.

It's a matter of good practice - if you'll have 1000 constants with bad naming, this will be difficult to understand by those who will read your code. And - I do not understand why use constants for numbers unless they have model-defined (or application-defined) meaning.

I.e. if you have some service 'FOO' with id=1, then `SERVICE_FOO_ID` constant with value 1 is normal solution, but if you want to create constant with value 1 for case `for($i=1; ...)` - that's sounds weird.

The common answer will be, of cause: it's opinion-bases. It's up to you.

Comment: Yes thank you... I am using the constant only in messgaes.. no in for loops :)